# Add-Computer to domain and rename even it object already exists

Tags: powershell, active-directory, rename

Happy Holidays folks,

I'm working on part of a script, this part renames the server and then joins it to the domain. The problem I'm running into is, we pre-stage some objects into AD into the proper OU. When I try to rename the server and rename it to that pre-staged object and add it to the domain I get an error

```
Add-Computer : Computer '10.10.204.105' was successfully joined to the new domain '$Domain', but renaming
it to '$Pre-stagedName' failed with the following error message: The account already exists.
```

I can get it to work if I *rename the server*, *restart it*, and then *add it to the domain* after, I'm trying to streamline the process a bit so it happens in one section. Below is what I'm currently trying

```
Rename-Computer -ComputerName $IP -NewName $HostName -LocalCredential $DefaultCred
Add-Computer -ComputerName $IP -NewName $HostName -Options JoinWithNewName -DomainCredential $AdminCred -DomainName $Domain -LocalCredential $DefaultCred -Force
```

Comment: This is really not a PS code issue. It's an enterprise ADDS thing. A machine will not receive proper ADDS property settings until a restart happens and it registered itself. Even if you did this manually in the normal way, via the control panel Systems properties GUI, the same catch22 is there.